# How to add a text note/annotation to a Chart.JS Tooltip Footer?

Tags: javascript, chart.js2

I’ve implemented a pretty simple line chart with Chart.JS in a Core 2.1 MVC app for a client.  The client would like the ability to add a text annotation (notes) to a given month.  Only one or two months out of a year will have a note/annotation and only one dataset will have any notes.  I’ve customized the tooltips with a callback that adds a footer to the tooltip.

I’m struggling with how to get the date in from the controller.  I’m currently writing out “notes” right after the data in the dataset so it looks something like this:

"datasets":[{"label":"Site","data":[50.0,25.0,65.0,null,null],"notes":["","Lot’s of snow this month","","",""],...}]

In the callback I can access the data like this.

```
data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index]
```

I’m struggling on how (or even if it possible) to read the custom “notes” array.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!